# How to get an imshow or surf objects from axes?

Tags: matplotlib

Once I've created a subplot in matplotlib, say by:

```
ax.imshow(my_data)
```

or in 3d mode:

```
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z etc.)
```

and then pass the axis object to another function: is there a way to get that axis object back as a variable, which we can manipulate?

e.g.

```
def my_func(ax):
     my_surf = ax.get_surface()
     my_surf.remove()
     ax.plot_surface(new_plot_data...)
```

Comment: Removing the mayavi tag as this question is not about mayavi